# Hitting enter key via bash redirection

Tags: linux, bash, io-redirection

How can I end inputting text to a process that reads from standard-in in one console from another console? - what is usually done by hitting the enter key.

Console 1: a C++ program reads from std::cin aslong the user does not hit enter (usual behavior).

Console 2: in a plain console I found out that I can send any text to the process in Console 1 by

```
echo "some text" >> /proc/18672/fd/0
```

(which simply writes to the standard-in of my process, which has the PID 18672).

This works but an important step is missing:

How can I end inputting e.g. "some text" from Console 2, or, how can I simulate hitting the enter-key for Console 1 from Console 2?

Using new line escapes, such as "\n" does not work.

Comment: What happens if you use control characters like "end of text" ETX (equals CTRL+C) or "end of transmission" EOT (equals CTRL+D) via `printf '\x03'` or `'\x04'`, respectively?

Comment: Unfortunately nothing: The program I am redirecting `printf '\x03'` to is simply printing '\x03' at the console but it's not interpreted as a key stroke.

Comment: Same in the very console (i.e. `printf '\x03'` without redirection)?

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtless better to design this some other way (OpenBSD removed
support for the TIOCSTI ioctl). With that in mind, first we cargo cult
some hopefully suitable C++ code that involves `std::cin` and get that
running in `/dev/pts/0`.

```
$ cat foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
int main() {
        int n;
        std::cin >> n;
        std::cout << n;
}
$ c++ foo.cpp
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
$ ./a.out
```

Then, over in a different terminal, we compile

```
// ttytickle.c - send characters via TIOCSTI
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int fd = open(*++argv, O_WRONLY);
        if (fd < 0) err(1, "open failed '%s'", *argv);
        char word[] = "42\n";
        char *wp = word;
        while(*wp != '\0') ioctl(fd, TIOCSTI, wp++);
        return 0;
}
```

and run the above:

```
$ make ttytickle && ./ttytickle /dev/pts/0
cc     ttytickle.c   -o ttytickle
```

and (assuming TIOCSTI is supported, the string is not too long, etc)
`./a.out` running in the `/dev/pts/0` terminal should have printed 42.

However, it might be better to design whatever you are trying to do some
other way, such as via a pipe or socket...

Answer (score 0):

The stdin of the process is just linked to its terminal - do a listing to see this, e.g.

```
> ll /proc/self/fd
total 0
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 11:32 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 11:32 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 Sep 12 11:32 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

So echo "text" effectively just outputs to that terminal, as you saw.
If what you are trying to achieve is just sending input to the process, maybe a FIFO can do what you want? E.g:

```
on tty1:
$ mkfifo input
$ cat > input <<-eof # send process some input (being careful not to close your output before completely done)
echo Hi
echo World
read ans
42
echo \$ans
eof
```

2nd process reads from the "input" fifo:

```
e.g. on tty1, in the same directory with the "input" fifo:
$ bash -x < input
+ echo Hi
Hi
+ echo World
World
+ read ans
+ echo 42
42
```